# no me imprime el var_dump en el lugar especificado

Tags: php, formularios

estoy aprendiendo php, y estaba haciendo un formulario estaba en la parte de validacion de datos previo a ponerlo en la bdd, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//RECOGER LOS DATOS DEL REGISTRO
 
   $nombre= isset($_POST['nombre'] ? $_POST['nombre'] : false;
   $apellido= isset($_POST['apellido'] ? $_POST['apellido']: false;
   $usuario = isset($_POST['nick'] ? $_POST['nick']: false;
   $email = isset($_POST['email'] ? $_POST['email']: false;
   $contraseña = isset($_POST['contra'] ? $_POST['contra']: false;

// VALIDAR DATOS DE REGISTRO

  $errores= array();

  if(!empty($nombre) && !is_numeric($nombre) && !preg_match('/[0-9]/',$nombre)){
     $nombre_validado = true;
    }else{

     $nombre_validado = false;
     $errores['nombre']='el nombre es invalido';
    }

  if(!empty($apellido) && !is_numeric($apellido) && !preg_match('/[0-9]/',$apellido)){
     $apellido_validado = true;
    }else{

     $apellido_validado = false;
     $errores['apellido']='el apellido es invalido';
    }

  if(!empty($nick)){
     $nick_validado = true;
     }else{

     $nick_validado = false;
     $errores['nick']= 'el campo usuario no puede estar vacio';
     }

  if(!empty($email) && filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
     $email_validado = true;
    }else{
     $email_validado = false;
     $errores['email'] = 'email invalido';
    }
  if(!empty($contraseña)){
     $contraseña_validado = true;
    }else{
     $contraseña_validado = false;
     $errores['contraseña'] = 'el campo contraseña no puede quedar vacio';

  $guardar_usuario = false;

 if(COUNT($errores) == 0){
    $guardar_usuario = true;
   }else{
    $_SESSION['errores'] = $errores;
    header('Location: index.php');
```

Hasta ahi el codigo de registro.php,luego en el lateral.php(es donde tengo el codigo html para la apariencia del formulario) tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<aside id="sidebar">
            <div id="login" class="bloque">
                <h3>Logueate</h3>
                <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email"/>
                    
                    <label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" name="contra"/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Entrar"/>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="registro" class="bloque">                 ¦  el codigo para imprimir el var_dump en
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['errores'])) : ?>     ¦->  apartado  de registrado de la pagina
                <?php var_dump($_SESSION['errores']);?>        ¦ 
                <?php endif; ?>                                ¦
```

no estoy mostrando todo el codigo porque si no seria muy larga la pregunta, pero todo esta correctamente cerrado y me saltaria algun error al abrir la pagina, el problema es que el var_dump no se imprime en
la seccion de registro, queda en blanco adjunto imagen.

[image]

en teoria ahi donde hice un circulo en rojo deberia imprimirse el var_dump con sus respectivos errores,
la cuestion es que luego de rellenar mal el formulario para ver si funciona el codigo esa parte queda en blanco como se ve en la imagen, que esta mal.
Disculpen por hacerlos leer mucho, gracias por su tiempo, si me falto agregar algo, avisen y lo proporciono. :)

Comment: Hola. isset($_SESSION['errores'] te devuelve true?. Verifica primero eso por favor

Comment: Verifica si el `if` se cumple como dice @RaulA. y si se cumple, entonces puede que alguna regla .css esté impidiendo ver el contenido. Prueba a ponerlo en otro sitio, por ejemplo en el área principal. Podría ser de utilidad también inspeccionar el código fuente de la página.

Comment: de que manera podria verificar si se cumple el if del isset, porque como dije anteriormente probe el var_dump sin poner el header y al rellenar erroneamente la pagina se redigiria y me mostraba una pagina sin otro contenido mas que el de los errores.